# My mousedown function isn't drawing lines from the most recent point, but instead from the top left corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

http://codepen.io/PartTimeCoder/pen/qZJdPW?editors=0010

This is the link to my CodePen.

My HTML and the CSS are working fine. But the JavaScript isn't working the way I want it to. It should draw a line from the last point you clicked at.

The JavaScript is below -

```
var randomColor = function() {
    return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
color = randomColor();

var height = window.innerHeight
var width = window.innerWidth

canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

var mouse = {};

var circle_count = 10;
var circles = [];

var generate = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < circle_count; i++) {
        circles.push(new circle());
    }
}

setInterval(generate, 7500);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousePos, false);
canvas.addEventListener('touch', mousePos, false);

function mousePos(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

Comment: That's what `.moveTo(0, 0)` does, it moves to the upper left corner, and then draws a line to wherever the mousedown happened ?

Comment: I'm wondering how to change that to the most recent click.

Comment: Do you want it like that? http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/XdxboL?editors=0010

Comment: Yes @PrzemysławMelnarowicz, just like that. Thanks! Just post an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save last clicked position before apply new one as on example:

codepen.io/themeler/pen/XdxboL?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

Each `mousedown` event calls `ctx.moveTo(0, 0)`, which positions it in the upper left.

Move this code out of your `mousedown` event, and it works fine:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKdjOY?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

Change the mouse variable to set your starting point

```
var mouse = {x : 0, y : 0};
```

and then the event handler to update the mouse variable to the latest point

```
canvas.addEventListener('touch', stuff);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", stuff);

function stuff(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.lineTo(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    ctx.stroke();
    mouse = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tpabh9ud/)